# How to add if, else-if and else condition in flutter custom widgets?

Tags: flutter

In my below code there is a custom container named **GunasoContainer** which has 2 custom text widgets **gunasoNum**, **status** and these text widgets's data is populated from api response, in **status** widget there can be one of 3 response 'Solved' or 'Declined' or 'pending', now I want to chnage the color of texts inside status widget based on type of response, for example: if status has response 'Solved' the font color should be green, and if status has response 'Declined' the font color should be red , if status has response 'pending' the font color should be yellow. now, how to add if, else-if and else condition in flutter custom widgets?

```
 GunasoContainer(

gunasoNum: response .response[index].grievance_no,
 status: response.response[index].status,
fontColor: response.response[index].status ==   'Solved'  ? Colors.white : Colors.deepOrange,  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change color u can do this way

```
GunasoContainer(
 gunasoNum: response .response[index].grievance_no,
 status: response.response[index].status,
 fontColor: response.response[index].status ==   'Solved'  ? Colors.white 
          : response.response[index].status ==   'Declined'? Colors.red
          : Colors.yellow,  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two different methods that I use to solve issues like this and quite honestly it comes down to personal preference. You can either create a function and pass the variable, in this case `response`, and then return a color from that function or you can use the conditional operator `?`.

Example with function, my personal go-to:

```dart
Color getGuanasoColor(String responseStatus) {
    switch (responseStatus) {
      case 'Solved':
        return Colors.green;
      case 'Declined':
        return Colors.red;
      case 'Pending':
        return Colors.yellow;
    }
  }
GunasoContainer(
  gunasoNum: response .response[index].grievance_no,
  status: response.response[index].status,
  fontColor: getGuanasoColor(response.response[index].status),
),
```

You had the conditional operator started, you just have to continue:

```dart
// This assumes that there are only three possible status states
fontColor: response.response[index].status == 'Solved' ? Colors.green : response.response[index].status == 'Declined' ? Colors.red : Colors.yellow,
```